# java 8 How to only return sum and count values from SummaryStatistics

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

As we all know,SummaryStatistics contain count, sum, min, average, max values.
Is it possibly more efficient if I only return count and sum values?If so,how to achieve that?

You can edit below code to show me:

```
Stream.of(0.55f, 0.45f, 0.5f, 0.65f, 0f).
            filter(i -> i > 0.5).mapToInt(i -> (int) (i * 100 - 50)).summaryStatistics()
```

Thank you

Comment: what is `SummaryStatistics`...please explain...are we talking about something like [IntSummaryStatistics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) here?

Comment: @nullpointer yes,it's IntSummaryStatistics or any other types like DoubleSummaryStatistics. summaryStatistics is a method name.

Comment: And you want only the sum and count to be accessed, so why is getSum and getCount not useful for you?

Comment: Sorry the question isn't clear in what you mean by *more efficient if I only return count and sum values* ?

Comment: Using a `DoubleStream` instead of a stream boxed `Float`s as starting point will have far more impact than not calculating the `min` and `max` (the average is only calculated if you ask for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are asking if you should traverse the source twice or once and use `IntSummaryStatistics`. Like would this be cheaper:

```
Stream.of(0.55f, 0.45f, 0.5f, 0.65f, 0f)
            .filter(i -> i > 0.5)
            .mapToInt(i -> (int) (i * 100 - 50))
            .count();

Stream.of(0.55f, 0.45f, 0.5f, 0.65f, 0f)
            .filter(i -> i > 0.5)
            .mapToInt(i -> (int) (i * 100 - 50))
            .sum();
```

Versus:

```
  IntSummaryStatistics summaryStatistics = Stream.of(0.55f, 0.45f, 0.5f, 0.65f, 0f)
            .filter(i -> i > 0.5)
            .mapToInt(i -> (int) (i * 100 - 50))
            .summaryStatistics();

    summaryStatistics.getSum();
    summaryStatistics.getCount();
```

Without measuring it's hard to say, but notice that in case of using `count` if there are no operations that clear the `SIZED` flag, some operations could be entirely skipped. For example:

```
long result = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            .mapToInt(x -> {
                System.out.println("mapping");
                return x;
            })
            .count();

System.out.println(result);
```

The `mapToInt` does not have to be processed at all here - and in fact in java-9 this will be skipped. The same optimization is not done with `IntSummaryStatistics`, where the count is computed always. That is not the case in your example, but a good thing to know about.

Since you say that you use `count` and `sum` either way, I would still choose `IntSummaryStatistics` over iterating twice. The only two other operations that are done inside `IntSummaryStatistics` are `Math.min` and `Math.max`.

Comment: Actually,I mean if there is a way to only get sum and count values,because I  don't need the other values in IntSummarryStatistics. I wonder is there a more efficient way than using IntSummarryStatistics, maybe a custom collector or a reduce method,I don't know how to get it.   Anyway thanks your explanation,that's nice.

Comment: @RickGeng you are probably looking for a performance issue where none exists. Yes writing a custom collector can be possible (not that hard at all) but there is no need to, you will hardly ever feel a difference